# What is the difference between document.getElementById('mybox') and mybox?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [document.getElementById(“someId”) Vs. someId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321839/document-getelementbyidsomeid-vs-someid)

For example I have an element with `id="mybox"` attribute, is there any difference between calling it with `document.getElementById('mybox')` and `mybox` directly, as I see both work same in most browsers? The jsfiddle shows **live example** http://jsfiddle.net/usmanhalalit/TmS3k/

If there is no difference then why `document.getElementById('mybox')` is so popular, is it a bad practice to call `mybox` directly?

Comment: See also [are DOM tree elements global variables here?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3434278/1048572)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Some** browsers in **some** rendering modes will create a global variable for each element with an id.

It is non-standard, won't work everywhere and definitely can't be depended upon.

Answer (score 6):

They don't "both work the same". IE introduced making element ids into global variables, other browsers copied it to some extent but don't fully support it. It's considered a very bad idea, just don't do it.

Comment: +1 thanks, but I have to choose only one answer.

Answer (score 4):

`mybox.value` does not work in most cases.  I believe IE is the only browser (and only some versions of it) that would support it.  In my Firefox browser, I get `mybox not defined` error message in the console.

Comment: +1 thanks, but I have to choose only one answer.