# HTML objects not visible to JavaScript in Firefox 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Is there any reason why I'm not able to see object values from JavaScript using Firefox, but IE and Chrome see them without problem?

For example:

```
<div>
<input type="text" id="clientID" />
<input type="submit" id="search" value="Submit" class="submitButton" />
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#searchDisputes").click(function () {
              if(clientID.value.toString() != "") {
                    //do something
              }
        }
}
</script>
```

Firefox tells me that `clientID` does not exist, however IE and Chrome work just fine.

I am able to access it using jQuery `$("#clientID")`, but before changing a good bit of code around, I would like to understand why this doesn't work in Firefox, but works ok in other browsers.

Comment: you aren't. $("clientID") is searching for html tag, not an ID

Comment: Should be `if ($('#clientID).val() ...` instead. `id` fields don't get put into the variable namespace, only `name` attributes do.

Comment: Sorry, I omitted the "#".  Fixed.

Comment: My question is not really about how to access the variable using JQuery (I know how to do that, I just had a typo in my initial post).  My question is really about why I can access something just using it's name in IE and Chrome, but not in FireFox.  Is IE and Chrome just allowing for non-standard access to the variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assuming that giving an element an id will create a global variable with the same name as the id containing a reference to the element. [There is no reason browsers should do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487078/what-is-the-difference-between-document-getelementbyidmybox-and-mybox/7487108#7487108).

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I wanted to know! =)